# Organizing The Custom Post Type with Taxonomies / Parent Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, categories, custom-taxonomy, tags

I am trying to make a custom post type called 'Songs'. It will have only two fields being 'Title' & 'Audio File'. I would also be creating a tag taxonomy field called 'Genres' so that admin can create geners on fly.

Now there are two more entities like Artists, Albums. I am lost as to how to organize my post type. It seems that every thing should be a post type but then how will i relate albums to songs and artists to albums.

Goal is to have this hierarchy

1 - Artist - (artist will have a tag of genre)
2 - Album
3 - Song

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a good idea to create two more hierarchical (category like) taxonomies, called Artists and Albums. This way, you'll be able to query your posts based on taxonomy / term relationships.

Basically, what I'm saying is this:

1. Artists -> **custom hierarchical taxonomy**
2. List item -> **custom hierarchical taxonomy**
3. Songs -> **custom post type**
4. Genres -> -> **custom tag taxonomy**

Please refer to this link from the Codex for a better understanding:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Short example taken directly from the Codex link above, below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**UPDATE**

How about creating two more custom post types, Artists and Albums, and having some metaboxes displayed on the Songs Custom Post Type (CPT) so that you can create a relationship between these ?

For example, in your Songs CPT, you could have a metabox or a custom field to hold the value for the Artists and for the Albums.

Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: But i want the user to add artist and albums with details not just name. If you can look into wpmovielibarary plugin. that has an option to create a library and movie it self is a post type.

Comment: That plugin seems to be free, why are you not using it if it could solve your problem ?

Comment: I am practicing. Taking ideas from it. But thats built on redux framework and i am not getting how the things are related to each other.

Comment: http://jancbeck.com/articles/relationships-between-wordpress-post-types

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for. However i am not sure if i will be able to use wordpress functions when using Artist post type as post meta in Songs post type.

Comment: It's possible. Tried and tested.